# Compute real signal from a discrete analytic signal

Tags: interpolation, analytic-signal

I have a 128MHz-wide down converted signal that gets processed in a FPGA via a polyphase filter bank to give 8x16 MHz baseband analytic signals. How do I convert this analytic signal to a real-valued signal? The Wikipedia article on analytic signal mentions that interpolation/up sampling will be required if the original signal was down converted. Here is how I plan to proceed:

1. Extract the real part of the analytic signal
2. interpolate (up-sample by a factor of 2, followed by a low pass filter)

Would the above give me a real-valued signal?

EDIT 1: I believe, I have to up-sample (i.e add zeros to every alternate point) and then use a low pass filter, e.g. a FIR to interpolate.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  If I understand correctly, the analytic signals you have are sampled at the Nyquist rate (no room for downsampling). If that's true, then you'll need to upsample by a factor of 2 **before** taking the real part.  Can you confirm that the analytic signals are nearly critically sampled (sampled just below the Nyquist rate) ?

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks! Yes, these bands are critically sampled. In this case, the real part of the analytic samples before or after up sampling are identical, right? Or am I missing something? By up sample here, I mean inserting zeroes for every second data.

Comment: OK. If you take the real part before upsampling, then you will get aliasing.  Give me a few minutes. I'll see if I can put together a quick example.

Comment: The basebands are all critically sampled so you have to upsample before taking the real part, because that operation is non linear.

Comment: Hi Emanuel, Sure I see the point. I need to upsample and apply an FIR filter low pass to remove the images. I have now up sampled by a factor of 2, and in need to a FIR filter with complex coefficients to complete the filtering operation. All my search is leading to Hilbert transformers. Do you know of any complex FIR filters? All impulse responses I get from a  typical filter design tool is real-valued.

Answer (score 1):

@user85858302: If designing a complex-valued bandpass filter is the solution to your problem, you can design such a filter without using the Hilbert transform. Start by using your favorite method for designing a real-valued N-tap FIR lowpass filter whose one-sided bandwidth is B Hz. That will give you N real-valued coefficients. Next, multiply those coefficients by a complex exponential whose frequency is Fc Hz. (Fc must be sufficiently less than half your data’s Fs sample rate.) That will produce N complex-valued coefficients that can be used in a tapped-delay line FIR filter block diagram. The complex-valued bandpass filter will have frequency response whose center frequency is Fc Hz and a bandwidth of 2B Hz.  Model this whole process in software to demonstrate what I'm sayin' here.

For those readers interested in both real-valued and complex-valued FIR filters, I suggest you have look at the following blog. You may well learn something new about FIR filters. http://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/808.php

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks - this does make clear sense to me. I shall give it a go and report results, hopefully with some illustrative plots.